# modify the file udp-sink.c cooja for refuse msg from all mots except one

Tags: c, simulation, iot, cooja

in my homework with cooja simulator i have 5 nodes ( 1 sink and 4 sender )
i want to do a modification in the file UDP-sink.c for refuse all the "Hello world" messages of the mote 3 and 4 and accept only from the mote 2 (UDP-sender.c) finely saturate the Mote 2 by receiving the "Hello world" messages of the mote 3, by modifying in the UDP_sink.c file ..

Comment: What have you tried and what exactly do you need help with?

Comment: I need to know how i can modify in the file (home/contiki/examples/ipv6/rpl-collect/udp-sink.c) where the sink refuse all hello world messages except from one node all that in cooja simulator

Comment: Are you looking for a text editor? You can open *.c files in notepad if you need to. What specifically are you looking for?

Comment: i know how to open the file i dont now where i must modify

Comment: https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/examples/ipv6/rpl-collect/udp-sink.c   {this is the code}